# How to parse response using Rxjs?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular8

I have observable result as response data:

```
this.response$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(...);
```

Then I need to parse this `this.response$` like:

```
let max = this.response$
      .pipe(max((a, b) => a["numberarea"] - b["numberarea"]))
      .subscribe();

let min = this.response$
      .pipe(max((a, b) => b["numberarea"] - a["numberarea"]))
      .subscribe();

let avg = this.response$.pipe(...avg)
let sum = this.response$.pipe(...sum)
```

After that I would like to pass variables max, min, avg, sum as `@Input()` to child components.

How to do that? If I subscribe on each statement it makes duplicates request to server:

```
let sum = this.response$.pipe(...sum).subscribe();
...
etc
```

So, my initial source is: `this.response$`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To prevent unwanted requests use `shareReplay` operator when you create a `response$` observable:

```
response$ = ...pipe(
  // other pipes
  shareReplay(1)
)
```

To pass values from observable into child component you should create your observables max, min etc.

```
max$ = this.response$
      .pipe(
         map(
           arrayOfItems => 
             arrayOfItems.sort(
               (a, b) => a["numberarea"] - b["numberarea"]
             )[0]
         )
       )
```

and use it in template with `async` pipe

```
[max]="max$ | async"
```

That pipe takes over subscription handling. But provides `null` into child component input when value isn't settled.

`*ngIf` directive comes to the rescue: child component won't init when value is falsy ('', 0, null etc.)

Comment: `.pipe(max((a, b) => a["numberarea"] - b["numberarea"]))` does not work

Comment: `response$` is array of objects

Comment: I done know but max() does not return me one max object

Comment: You'd better mention that :) max operator calculates stream values.
I will update my answer according to that knowledge

Comment: This gives me undefined in console: `this.response$
      .pipe(max((a, b) => (a["numberarea"] < b["numberarea"] ? -1 : 1)))
      .subscribe((data) => console.log(data));`

Answer (score 1):

you can use `shareReply` without the number of emits. Then only one request will be sent and no subscribes will trigger it again, only when `this.route.paramMap` emits itself.

```js
// Also `paramMap` returns a `Map` and you need to use `.get` method.

this.response$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
  map(param => parseInt(param.get('numberarea'), 10)),
  shareReplay(),
);

// counts on every emit
let numbers = this.response$.pipe(
  scan((result, param) => {
    return [...result, param];
  }, []),
  filter(params => params.length > 0),
  map(params => ({
    max: Math.max(...params),
    max: Math.min(...params),
    avg: params.reduce((s, n) => s + n, 0) / params.length),
).subscribe();

// or per variable, subscribe or use async pipe.

let max$ = this.response$.pipe(
  scan((result, param) => {
    return [...result, param];
  }, []),
  filter(params => params.length > 0),
  map(params => Math.max(...params)),
);
let min$ = this.response$.pipe(
  scan((result, param) => {
    return [...result, param];
  }, []),
  filter(params => params.length > 0),
  map(params => Math.min(...params)),
);
let avg$ = this.response$.pipe(
  scan((result, param) => {
    return [...result, param];
  }, []),
  filter(params => params.length > 0),
  map(params => params.reduce((s, n) => s + n, 0) / params.length),
);

// counts on subscription complete
let max = this.response$
      .pipe(max((a, b) => a - b))
      .subscribe();

let min = this.response$
      .pipe(max((a, b) => b - a))
      .subscribe();

let avg = this.response$.pipe(...avg)
let sum = this.response$.pipe(...sum)
```

Comment: Yes, but it calls response$ twice, first when I handle routing and then when I appy another rxjs rul to response$

Comment: but do you know that paramMap emits once per navigation?

Comment: params are not presenrted in `this.response$`. `this.response$` is response from server

Comment: Lets assume you have strema data `response$`. I need apply to this others rxjs rules to get aggrigations data. So, when I apply it calls server the equal times

Comment: I've updated the answer as an example how you could do it, but the first map should be defined by you, because it's unclear what is payload type of `this.response$`

Comment: Ah, I see, it wasn't clear for the question, then `shareReplay` definitely better solution.

Comment: Yes, but how to await `response$` to use next `this.zu$ = this.response$.pipe(
      max((a, b) => b["n"] - a["n"])
    );`

Comment: Also I've updated the answer with info about `share` operator, perhaps it fits better.

Comment: What is `max`? I don't know such a rxjs operator.

Comment: It exists, it find max element from the steam

Comment: Problem is that second stream does not when first streama gets response

Comment: can't find it in the list https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/complete, I think you can try to use the stream from my answer.

Comment: Aha, then I think you need `shareReplay()` without arguments. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: @satanTime: See here for info on `max` operator: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/max

Comment: Thanks! I think the problem then that it counts max on complete, is it desired behavior? Then simply use `this.response$` definition without the second part from my answer and it should do it.

Comment: I faced with problem I have `res: [{}. {}];` as array of objects, So I need to findand return object where property from object is max.

Comment: `this.response$
      .pipe(
        max((a, b) => a["numberarea"] - b["numberarea"]),
        take(1)
      )
      .subscribe((data) => console.log(data));`

Comment: this is what `let numbers` does. you can remove `map(param => parseInt(param.get('numberarea'), 10)),` to get original array of all parameters, but then you need to adopt `scan` logic.

Comment: I added an example how to have different streams that recalculate values on an emit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
        of(params.get('numberarea'))
      )
    ).subscribe((res) => {
      // Do your stuff
    });
```

Comment: that is not what I expect, I want to do this in one steam. I need to apply rxjs to `response$` and create another observables like mix, max, avg